# dplyr fill missing time series values with NA and by group

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, plyr

I have a data frame like so:

```
library(tidyverse)

#make some data
df <- tibble(ID = c(1, 1, 2, 2),
            Year = c(2000, 2003, 2000, 2003),
             Value = c(1, 1, 1, 1))

     ID  Year Value
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1  2000     1
2     1  2003     1
3     2  2000     1
4     2  2003     1
```

Which is missing the year 2001, 2002, 2004 and 2005. I would like to groupby the `ID` column and fill the `Value` column with NaN.  My expected output is:

```
wanted <- tibble(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
                 Year = c(2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005),
                 Value = c(1, NaN, NaN, 1, NaN, NaN, 1, NaN, NaN, 1, NaN, NaN))

      ID  Year Value
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1  2000     1
 2     1  2001   NaN
 3     1  2002   NaN
 4     1  2003     1
 5     1  2004   NaN
 6     1  2005   NaN
 7     2  2000     1
 8     2  2001   NaN
 9     2  2002   NaN
10     2  2003     1
11     2  2004   NaN
12     2  2005   NaN
```

I have looked into the complete and fill functions within the tidyverse, but I can't seem to quite get it.

Ideally I would like to give a sequence I would prefer in the `Year` column, and then fill all missing years in the `Value` column with NaN.  I have only supplied a simplified example here. In this case the wanted sequence would be `seq(2000, 2005, 1)`.

Comment: why is `2001` not in the sequence `complete(df, ID, Year = min(Year):max(Year))`

Comment: @akrun My guess is `2001` should be there. The OP just provided a simplified example with only adding `2002`, but this example is confusing, not helping.

Comment: Yes sorry about that, it is a typo, I have edited it.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `complete` function to do the job.

```
library(tidyverse)

df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  complete(Year = full_seq(Year, period = 1), fill = list(Value = NaN)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: This would work in this example. I guess I should edit again.  Lets say I need to fill 2004 and 2005 as well, then I need to fill based on sequence.

Comment: I have edited it to better capture my true problem.  Apologies.

Comment: @StefanoPotter No worries. Your example is clear to me now. Thanks.